# What's going on in this snippet regarding the representation of n in pc[i]

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, memory-layout

I have no idea what's going on. Instead of a uint8_t, I would have guessed that we need to cast to a pointer of a 1 Byte type like char or bool to achieve this behavior. I guess the reverse nature is due to endianness?

EDIT: I found my thinking error, of course a uint8_t is of size 8bit = 1byte, just like bool and char (at least on my machine). I mistakenly took the sizeof(pc) into thoughts, which is a pointer and therefore 8byte on my 64 machine. Now everything makes sense also with the endianness.

Thx, i appreciate your help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::hex;

int main()
{

int n{0x12345678};
cout << "01|    n=0x" << hex << n << endl;

uint8_t* pc{(uint8_t*)&n};
cout << "02|    n[0]=0x" << hex << +pc[0] 
    << ", n[1]=0x" << +pc[1]    // small trick: + to var to use as number
    << ", n[2]=0x" << +pc[2]
    << ", n[3]=0x" << +pc[3] << endl;

pc[1]=0xab;
pc[2]=0xcd;
cout << "03|    n[0]=0x" << hex << +pc[0] 
    << ", n[1]=0x" << +pc[1]
    << ", n[2]=0x" << +pc[2]
    << ", n[3]=0x" << +pc[3] << endl;
return 0;

}
```

output:

```
01|    n=0x12345678
02|    n[0]=0x78, n[1]=0x56, n[2]=0x34, n[3]=0x12
03|    n[0]=0x78, n[1]=0xab, n[2]=0xcd, n[3]=0x12
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse"? What would be "forward" to you? I.e. what output would you expect? Why?

Comment: Note that `(uint8_t*)&n` causes undefined behavior according to C++ standard.

Comment: Yes indeed, the "reversing" is due to the endianness of the machine in question.  You're running this on a little-endian machine, which is why the least significant byte of `n` is found in `pc[0]`.

Comment: This is a strict aliasing violation. `uint8_t` != `char`

Comment: @Yunnosch advocates of big-endian architectures point out that the output from this would be "similar to" the value itself: `n[0]=0x12, n[1]=0x34, n[2]=0x56, [3]=0x78`.  I am **NOT** attempting to start a holy war here, merely observing what their argument is.

Comment: Attempting to alias an `int` as an array of `uint8_t` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your issue is Endianness:  the ordering of bytes in a mulitibyte number.

### Little Endian:

Least significant byte first.
Given 0x12345678, the value will be stored in Little Endian as:

```
0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12
```

### Big Endian:

Most significant byte first.
Given 0x12345678, the value will be store in Big Endian as:

```
0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78
```

Endianness is a processor level definition.  Different processors store mutibyte numbers in different methods.